# How to decrease the line spacing in this python program?

Tags: python, text-formatting

I was learning nested loops, and ran into this problem with line spacing between each of x's lines.

```
numbers = [2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7]

for i in numbers:
    for j in range(0, i):
        print("x", end='')
    print('\n')
```

Following is the output of my code:

```
xx

xx

xx

xx

xxxxxxx

xxxxxxx
```

What changes should I make in my code so that an additional line is not present between each x's line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `print("\n")` with `print()`, as print already prints a trailing newline by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is working, I have tried

```py
numbers = [2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7]

for i in numbers:
    for j in range(0, i):
        print("x", end='')
    print()
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to avoid an unnecessary inner `for` loop:

```py
numbers = [2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7]

for i in numbers:
    print('x' * i)
```

An alternative with [f-strings](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-pad-fill-string-by-variable-python):

```py
filler = 'x'
for i in numbers:
    print(f'{filler:{filler}<{i}}')
```

If you wanted you could also do this in a single `print` statement (without loops) using a built-in like `map`:

```py
print(*map(lambda i: 'x' * i, numbers), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing such insightful information. I can't upvote your answer cause of my low reputation though.

Comment: @AryanBakshi no problem! glad it was helpful at least.