# What is the use of an empty string in the following code

Tags: python

This program prints out a simple 'F' shape using nested loops. I've read somewhere that an empty string means whatever input the user gives will be stored in them. Is this true? If not, whats the use of an empty string in a non-input program?

```
numbers = [2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
for x_count in numbers:
    output = ''
    for count in range(x_count):
        output += 'x'
    print(output)
```

Comment: it's to start out with an empty string and then add characters to it in the loop. try to print `output` inside the inner for loop and you'll see how it changes over the iterations

Comment: This seems very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69618715/10237506).

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is initialised as a string.

If you wouldn't initialise it before going into the for-loop the python interpreter wouldn't know it is a string and thereby couldn't perform the `+=` operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to initilize the value of the variable "output".
If it wouldn't be their you will get an error when assiging output += 'x' for the first time because output is undefiend there.

Answer (score 1):

The usage relates to the use of  `+=` operator.

The variable `output` is initialized with `''`
and operator `+=` adds any other part to it.

You can replace `+=` with `output = output + 'x'` but the initialization is still needed. Just try to comment `output = ''` out for possible better understanding.